# Splitting a String after a specific symbol

Tags: java, string, split

I have a String (format of an email) for example `random@abc`.

I want to get the part behind the `@`. So in this example the `abc`.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String str = "random@abc";
// get the index of `@` and then get content after it.
String res = str.substring(str.indexOf('@') + 1);
System.out.println(res); // abc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
String email = "something@abc.com";
String res = email.split("@")[1];
System.out.println(res);
```